# Rails: Default sort order for a rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to specify a default sort order in my model.

So that when I do a `.where()` without specifying an `.order()` it uses the default sort. But if I specify an `.order()`, it overrides the default.

Answer (score 593, accepted):

### `default_scope`

This works for Rails 4+:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

For Rails 2.3, 3, you need this instead:

```
default_scope order('created_at DESC')
```

For Rails 2.x:

```
default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC'
```

Where `created_at` is the field you want the default sorting to be done on.

Note: **<sup>ASC</sup>** is the code to use for Ascending and **<sub>DESC</sub>** is for descending (`desc`, **NOT** `dsc` !).

### `scope`

Once you're used to that you can also use `scope`:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :confirmed, :conditions => { :confirmed => true }
  scope :published, :conditions => { :published => true }
end
```

For Rails 2 you need `named_scope`.

`:published` scope gives you `Book.published` instead of 
`Book.find(:published => true)`.

Since Rails 3 you can 'chain' those methods together by concatenating them with periods between them, so with the above scopes you can now use `Book.published.confirmed`.

With this method, the query is not actually executed until actual results are needed (lazy evaluation), so 7 scopes could be chained together but only resulting in 1 actual database query, to avoid performance problems from executing 7 separate queries.

You can use a passed in parameter such as a date or a user_id (something that will change at run-time and so will need that 'lazy evaluation', with a lambda, like this:

```
scope :recent_books, lambda 
  { |since_when| where("created_at >= ?", since_when) }
  # Note the `where` is making use of AREL syntax added in Rails 3.
```

Finally you can disable default scope with:

```
Book.with_exclusive_scope { find(:all) }
```

or even better:

```
Book.unscoped.all
```

which will disable any filter (conditions) or sort (order by).

*Note that the first version works in Rails2+ whereas the second (unscoped) is only for Rails3+*

---

**So**
... if you're thinking, hmm, so these are just like methods then..., yup, that's exactly what these scopes are!
They are like having `def self.method_name ...code... end` but as always with ruby they are nice little syntactical shortcuts (or 'sugar') to make things easier for you!

In fact they are Class level methods as they operate on the 1 set of 'all' records.

Their format is changing however, **with rails 4 there are deprecation warning when using #scope without passing a callable object.** For example scope :red, where(color: 'red') should be changed to `scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }`.

As a side note, when used incorrectly, **default**_scope can be misused/abused.
This is mainly about when it gets used for actions like `where`'s limiting (filtering) the *default* selection (a **bad idea** for a default) rather than just being used for ordering results.
For `where` selections, just use the regular named scopes. and add that scope on in the query, e.g. `Book.all.published` where `published` is a named scope.

In conclusion, scopes are really great and help you to push things up into the model for a 'fat model thin controller' DRYer approach.

Comment: as an aside, is there a way to reference the default scope as a sort order? like `Book.order(:default_scope)`

Comment: I don't believe so.  You would just use Book.abc where abc is a scope used for sorting, e.g. `some_name sort(:field_to_sort_by)`, i.e. a class level method.

Comment: would not it be more secure to do `default_scope { order("#{table_name}.created_at DESC") }` ?

Comment: sice Rails4 there's the safe and simple syntax `default_scope order(created_at: :desc)`

Comment: Rails 4: `default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }`

Comment: At least `4.2.6` seems to sort by `updated_at` not `created_at`.

Comment: Is there a problem you can think of about ordering by id? As long as it is generated by a sequence there should not be any other side effects right? And, comparing numbers is faster than comparing dates.

Comment: @AinTohvri is right. This just caught me by surprise in Rails 4.2. Why sort by `updated_at` by default? :-|

Comment: @fabro some people use UUIDs for primary keys

Comment: Please note that in Rails 5, (and probably R4 too), using the default scope to apply ordering will break any existing code that relies on ordering by a different column. If you want to order by a different column you'll have to use `MyModel.unscoped.order(:some_other_col)` or `MyModel.reorder(:some_other_col)`.

Comment: @reto's comment refers to an article that is now only available on archive.org at: https://web.archive.org/web/20130723052449/https://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2012/03/be-careful-using-default_scope-and-order.html

Answer (score 116):

A quick update to Michael's excellent answer above.

For Rails 4.0+ you need to put your sort in a block like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order('created_at DESC') }
end
```

Notice that the order statement is placed in a block denoted by the curly braces.

They changed it because it was too easy to pass in something dynamic (like the current time). This removes the problem because the block is evaluated at runtime. If you don't use a block you'll get this error:

> Support for calling #default_scope without a block is removed. For example instead of `default_scope where(color: 'red')`, please use `default_scope { where(color: 'red') }`. (Alternatively you can just redefine self.default_scope.)

As [@Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2056117/dan) mentions in his comment below, you can do a more rubyish syntax like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

or with multiple columns:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order({begin_date: :desc}, :name) }
end
```

Thanks [@Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2056117/dan)!

Comment: In rails 4 this can also be written as `default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }` if, like me, you try to minimize sql syntax in rails.<br/>If you have multiple columns to order by and you want to use the new syntax you may need to wrap the desc columns in mustaches like this `default_scope { order({begin_date: :desc}, :name) }`

Comment: @Dan - Not only does your comment eliminate SQL, it is a more Rubyish syntax.

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer used to be correct - default scopes were the only way to do this. However, default scopes are actually chained (the scope itself is applied to any further scopes/calls), and this can cause some [unpredictable behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65400302/1864042). Default scopes are thus widely considered something to avoid at almost all cost.

It's important to note that given your original question, default scope doesn't actually *quite* satisfy this, since in order to actually skip the default scope, any model has to explicitly specify `.unscoped` first. That means that if `order(:something)` is called, without `.unscoped`, the result is actually more similar to `order(:default).order(:something)`. `:something` takes priority, sure, but `:default` is still there, so now there's a multicolumn sort, which might not be desired. The original question specifies that the default sort order be ignored if another order is called, and default scope, without `.unscoped`, doesn't meet that requirement.

[Since Rails 6](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34480), however, there is now `implicit_order_column`, which can be set on a model.

```ruby
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  self.implicit_order_column = 'publish_date'
end
```

This will cause the model to order by that column by default, instead of the primary key. Like the default, built in sort (which uses id), however, if a different order is specified (with `order(:something)`), this implicit ordering is ignored, not chained: `.order(:something)` does not result in a multicolumn sort, and the need for `.unscoped` is gone.

One of the most common uses of this is when switching to UUID's as primary keys. By default, Rails will still order on the primary key, but since that key is now a meaningless byte string, this order is now similarly meaningless. Thus to replicate the old behavior, such that `SomeModel.last` should return the most recently created record by default, simply set this on ApplicationRecord:

```ruby
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.implicit_order_column = 'created_at'
end
```

Note that it *is* theoretically possible to cause an error here. `created_at` is not unique - it's stored with microsecond precision, but in theory it's possible to create to records with the exact same `created_at` time, and thus, any returned results that depended only on that would be non-deterministic - subsequent calls might return different records. It is a low enough chance, however, that it's often considered safe to do this - particularly if the code does not depend on a deterministic result here (which, it probably shouldn't - if deterministic results are needed, referencing the primary key or some other unique column is better when possible).

It's also worth noting that `created_at` (or whatever column is used), by default, does not have a key. This means selects will slightly slow down doing this, at least until a key is added to that column to fix this.

Finally, `implicit_order_column` has limited functionality - it is not possible to set even the sort order, much less to do more complex things like multi-column sorts. If that functionality is required, `default_scope` is still the way only to go.

Comment: Ascending? Descending? I get that it can't be customized, but is the behavior defined somewhere?

Comment: That ... depends on activerecord. For example, calling SomeModel.all doesn't order it at all (it doesn't by default without implicit_order_column). Calling SomeModel.all.first orders ASC, then takes the first record. SomeModel.all.last orders DESC and takes the first record. This just causes it to behave in the same way id does naturally, but on some other column.

Answer (score 6):

You can use default_scope to implement a default sort order
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html

Comment: The link is working but there is nothing about `default_scope` on that page, because it has been refactored from `ActiveRecord::Base` into `ActiveRecord::Scoping::Default::ClassMethods` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html)