# Sort by date attribute in rails list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I have a table in my app that currently displays items in the order in which they are created. I would like them to sort by my date attribute (<%= o.dateg %>) in chronological order. Whats the proper rails way to do this?

Controller:

```
def show
 @occasion = Occasion.find(params[:id])
end
```

View:

```
   <% @user.occasions.each do |o| %>
          <td><%= o.name %></td>
          <td><%= o.pname %></td>
          <td><%= o.dateg %></td>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try getting them sorted from the database.

Comment: and i could do that by..added controller code

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393687/how-do-i-set-a-default-sort-order-for-a-rails-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have that, right?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occassions
end
```

You can change the `has_many` to:

```
has_many :occasions, order: 'dateg desc'
```

Answer (score 3):

In the view you can use `sort` e.g.

`@user.occasions.sort {|a,b| b.dateg <=> a.dateg }.each do |o|`

(this will be reverse chronological)

However you should really be doing this in the model not in the view, a named scope would work fine:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occasions
  scope :recent_occasions, order('dateg desc')
end
```

Then use

`@user.recent_occasions.each do |o|`