# Sorting! Each blocks, attributes Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.15,

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

I have an app that manages images associated with buses. My problem is that I can't figure out how to sort an each block by a particular BusImage attribute, :thumb_order instead of the BusImage id.

A Bus has many BusImages.

The instance variables are defined in the Bus controller under Show as...

```
@bus = Bus.find(params[:id]
@bus_images = BusImage.find(:all, :order => 'thumb_order asc')
```

And I'm calling these instance variables in the Bus Show page like this:

```
@bus.bus_images.each do |bus_image|
  bus_image.thumb_order
  (other attributes, etc)
end
```

But no matter how I change the :order method on the @bus_images it doesn't affect the view at all. When I tried using the method on @bus, because Buses don't have thumb_order column, just stares at me blankly.

Answer (score 0):

I see no link between `@bus_images` and your next bloc `@bus.bus_images`. These are 2 completely different variables.

If you want to sort your bus images, try this :

```
@bus.bus_images.sort_by(&:thumb_order').each do |bus_image|
```

Or set a default order on your BusImage model, as [Default sort order for a rails model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393687/default-sort-order-for-a-rails-model)

Answer (score 0):

I find this syntax a little easier to remember, but take your pick:

```
@bus.bus_images.sort_by{|bi| bi.thumb_order}
```