# Rails sorting gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'd like to create a gem that modifies `ActiveRecord::Base` `select` methods. For instance, when I include my gem and type:

```
Somemodel.all
```

it should return an array ordered by id as normally but in descending order instead of ascending. I have no clue how it should look. I would not like to create additional methods like:

```
Somemodel.where(name: "John").revert_it
```

but simply do:

```
Somemodel.where(name: "John")
```

I was wondering about modifying `ActiveRecord::Base` methods, but it does not make any sense. IMO the best way is to callback after every `ActiveRecord::Base` method that will do it.

Comment: I would create the additional methods.  It'll be really confusing for whoever comes in after you and can't work out why the order is reversed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default sort order for a rails model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393687/default-sort-order-for-a-rails-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got fully valid answer:

```
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
     default_scope { order(id: 'desc') }
    end
  end
```

Above method should be inside some module and then module included within some model class

Comment: while I would not encourage this for the same reasons everyone else has mentioned see my comment on @Drenmi's post for the correct way to make this addition to ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will consider it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ActiveRecord` method [`default_scope`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class) to achieve this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope { order("id DESC") }

end

MyModel.all
# => SELECT * FROM my_models ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: ye that's the idea! but I need that as module

Comment: ye that's the idea! but I need that as module – mike927 1 hour ago
     
 
@mike927 thats fine you can make this fairly easily module `ARExtension; extend ActiveSupport::Concern; module ClassMethods;default_scope { order("id DESC") };end; end; ActiveRecord.Base.send(:include,ARExtension)` This will add that default scope to all objects that inherit from AR Base and that do not overwrite the default scope.

Answer (score 1):

It's not advisable to modify any core `ActiveRecord` methods (unless you have a really good reason), because that will make lot of confusion in future.

Even if you are thinking of modifying the select , you have make sure that you always return an `ActiveRecord relation` , so that it can be chained with as the standard way,

For your example, AR already has a method

`User.all.reverse`

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Comment: `User.all.reverse_order` might be a bit more efficient (lets DB return them in reverse order as opposed to getting the array and reversing it)

Comment: @sawa, sorry .. not a native English speaker :)