# Specify Postgresql DB default collation for a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4.2+ and Postgres 9.4 project and I need to change how Postgres orders items in a query.  The default settings seem to ignore whitespace and I need a strategy that takes white space into account.  After running `\l` in psql, I see the db has `Collate` set to `en_US.UTF-8` and `Ctype` set to `en_US.UTF-8`.

**Updated 12/30/15 4:14pm**

I have the following Activities with a name column with the following names:

```
Code1A East
Code1A West
Code1 AEast
Code1 AWest
```

When I execute the following query in Rails

```
Activity.order(name: :asc)
```

I expected to get back a list of Activities in the following order.

```
Code1 AEast
Code1 AWest 
Code1A East
Code1A West
```

or maybe even

```
Code1A East
Code1A West
Code1 AEast
Code1 AWest
```

Instead I get

```
Code1A East
Code1 AEast
Code1A West
Code1 AWest
```

It appears to be disregarding the space in the name.  I noted in a comment below, I was able to get the Rails app to create a DB with a specific collation by adding the following to database.yml

```
development:
  ...other keys...
  encoding: utf8
  collation: sv_SE.UTF-8
  ctype: sv_SE.UTF-8
  template: template0
```

But I don't know which collation setting will pick a "better" sort order.

Comment: Is the ordering PostgreSQL-specific? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393687/default-sort-order-for-a-rails-model) SO topic might help. You can specify a default order for each model whenever you run a query.

Comment: This is a problem I want to correct at the DB level.

Comment: Please post an example of a query result that doesn't match your expectation. Sorting doesn't ignore the white spaces by default.

Answer (score 2):

The collation setting on Postgres is determined by the server, not your connection to it, [per the Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/locale.html), and as such there's no way to make it just a setting in `database.yml`. To permanently change the value, you'll need to permanently modify your server.

However, you can force a different collation for sorting on a per-query basis, in a couple ways:

```
SELECT * FROM things ORDER BY name COLLATE "C" ASC;
```

Will use the `C` collation, which is probably what you're looking for, and accomplishes the same result as:

```
SELECT * FROM things ORDER BY name USING ~<~;
```

*(see [this SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/507c2/8) for a live example)*

Hope that helps!

Comment: I just tried adding `encoding: utf8, collation: sv_SE.UTF-8, template: template0` to the development group in database.yml, and re-created the database and I can see the new collation settings on the DB.

Comment: @CodeKing: sure, but that setting will only change when you rebuild the server. If you provision, say, a new database in Heroku or AWS, those settings will likely not be respected (so be cautious when you deploy to production!).