# What the best way to have the default order in rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a project which requires to display collection or association in different pages with id order in a list. The database is PostgreSQL.

Normally the data will be stored in the order of ids by default. However, my database is not like that and will always return in a different order if you don't apply orders, I.e [1432, 1430, 1401, 1400].

Currently I have to manually add the order scope for each association. But it's looks fussy. Even in one model I have to add multiple times.

```
class A
  has_many :xxx, -> { order(:id)}
  has_many :yyy, -> { order(:id)}
  has_many :zzz, -> { order(:id)}
end

class B
  has_many :aaa, -> { order(:id)}
  has_many :bbb, -> { order(:id)}
  has_many :xxx, -> { order(:id)}
end

...
```

Therefore, I am looking for a better solution. One solution I can think of, is to add the `default_scope` to `ActiveRecord::Base` class. But I heard of the `default_scope` is an anti-parttern?

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
   default_scope { order(:id) }
end
```

Feel free to give me any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: what does mean by this `will always return in a different order if you don't apply orders` ? could you please try to explain by example for better understanding of question ?

Comment: @Gabbar I mean it doesn't return as id order. For example, `@library.books` return me the id `[5,4,3,2,1]`, but I expected to be `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: If you want only order by id then you can do this as  - `has_many :xxx, -> { order("id ASC")}, class_name: 'B', foreign_key: 'b_id'` . let me know if it helped you.

Comment: @Gabbar Thanks for your answer. But you may not understand my question. My problem related to several tables and even the whole database.

Comment: can you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393687/default-sort-order-for-a-rails-model

Answer (score 0):

For your case default_scope is good option, but if you don't want to use default_scope, you can use model concerns and define your scope in concerns and include it to your models.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

```
module DefaultScope

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :asc_order, -> { order(id: :asc) }
  end
end
```

```
class ModelName < ApplicationRecord
  include DefaultScope
end
```