# What the difference between implicit_order_column and default_scope in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

What the difference between:

```
self.implicit_order_column = 'id'
```

and

```
default_scope { order('id ASC') }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.implicit_order_column` lets you use another column then the primary key as the implicit ordering column. This effects the way that methods like `.first` and `.last` work:

```
User.class_eval do 
  self.implicit_order_column = 'created_at'
end

User.first
# => SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."updated_at" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]

User.last
# => SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Setting `self.implicit_order_column = 'id'` is utterly pointless since the default is the primary key column anyways. The `implicit_order_column` is of course not used if you provide an explicit order. It does not actually change any other scopes spawned off the class.

`default_scope` on the other hand tacks on a default scope to any scopes that you spawn off the class.

```
irb(main):001:0> User.all
   (0.5ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, role: "admin", created_at: "2020-11-08 19:31:31", updated_at: "2020-11-08 19:31:47">]>
irb(main):002:1* User.class_eval do
irb(main):003:1*   default_scope { order(id: :asc) }
irb(main):004:0> end
=> [#<Proc:0x00000000043703a8 (irb):3>]
irb(main):005:0> User.all
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, role: "admin", created_at: "2020-11-08 19:31:31", updated_at: "2020-11-08 19:31:47">]>
irb(main):006:0>
```

The difference here is not immediately apparent. But if you consider that in the SQL world a query with no order clause will not return the records in a determinate order (its implementation dependent) and here we are actually getting the records in a determinate order. Om many RDBMS the results will be hard to destinguish as they might return the records in the order they are modified (if they feel like it).

Seems brilliant until you realize how non-intuitive `default_scope` is and how many bugs it leads to down the line.

```
irb(main):006:0> User.all.order(:created_at)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC, "users"."created_at" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, role: "admin", created_at: "2020-11-08 19:31:31", updated_at: "2020-11-08 19:31:47">]>
irb(main):007:0>
```

Or this example:

```
irb(main):001:1* User.class_eval do
irb(main):002:1*   default_scope { where(admin: true) }
irb(main):003:0> end
=> [#<Proc:0x0000000002bde460 (irb):2>]
irb(main):004:0> User.new
   (0.6ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
=> #<User id: nil, role: "visitor", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, admin: true>
```

Yikes! `default_scope` is thus widely considered evil.

See:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34480
- https://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2013/06/15/default_scope-is-evil/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/ha6gqj/default_scope_is_evil/

Comment: Here's a gotcha: unfortunately, `implicit_order_column` only applies to scopes on the object itself, and not on associations, so you need to specify `class Cat; has_many :whiskers, -> { order(timestamp: "asc") }` even if `class Whisker; self.implicit_order_column = 'timestamp' ` -- iirc `default_scope` applied to associations as well

Comment: It is applied on associations, but only with `first/last`, eg `cat.whiskers.first`. It's not applied when iterating over the association, eg `cat.whiskers.each` (neither with `Whisker.all.each`).

Comment: @Zubin thats a good clarification of what I meant by "It does not actually change any other scopes spawned off the class." - when you're calling `each` you're implicitly spawning a scope.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup! In your first example, am I crazy or have you got the wrong column listed in the SQL output? Wouldn't the output be `ORDER BY created_at` and not `ORDER BY updated_at`?

Comment: @TobiasFünke yeah thats most likely a copypasta error